# Laravel adding several javascript scripts

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have a Laravel's blade.php file and I've added two js to it:

```
    @extends('layouts.master')

    @section ('content')

    @include('layouts.tours2_create_table')

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/add_passenger.js') }}"</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/create_tour_ajax.js') }}"></script>

    @endsection
```

My 1st js (add_passenger.js) works, but 2nd (create_tour_ajax.js) doesn't!

To make things simple, I shortened code in both files to:

add_passenger.js:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("Script_1");
    });
```

create_tour_ajax.js

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("Script_2");
    });
```

So, when I load page, I see:

[image]

I think I am doing some stupid newbee mistake:) Please help:)

UPDATE: 
I've just missed a bracket:))))[image]

PLEASE DELETE MY QUESTION:))))

Answer (score 0):

```
   @extends('layouts.master')

    @section ('content')

    @include('layouts.tours2_create_table')


    @push('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/add_passenger.js') }}"</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/create_tour_ajax.js') }}"></script>
   @endpush

    @endsection
```

after that put this in the master layout where you want the scripts to load

```
   @stack('scripts')
```

this should fix your issue.

Comment: :P :P :P :P hmm i c